# How would you implement a ROS subscriber in an existing QT Creator GUI project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, ros

I installed the **ROS plugin** for QT on ubuntu, but if I create a subscriber node in the project it gives me an error on `#include "ros / ros.h"`
From what I understand I need to create a workspace with catkin, but how do I merge the project I already have with the workspace?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry it's a typo here, of course in the code is written correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a catkin workspace you simple need to create a new package and build the project there; you can see a tutorial on that [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage). To put it briefly, you can create a package inside `~/<your_workspace>/src` that depends on `roscpp` this command `catkin_create_pkg your_new_package std_msgs roscpp`. You should then put your `.cpp` files in the `<your_new_package>/src` directory and `.hpp` files in the `<your_new_package>/include` directory. All you need to do after that is actually make it build via catkin and cmake. Since ros packages build with cmake this is done by editing the `CMakeLists.txt` file inside each package. You can find more info on that [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29). Essentially you want to make sure your source files are captured and build. It could look something like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(your_new_node_name)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs genmsg)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(your_qt_executable src/your_source_file.cpp)
target_link_libraries(your_qt_executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#uncomment this if other deps are needed
#add_dependencies(your_qt_executable some_other_dependency)
```

Comment: now that i have my workspace, my package and my subscriber, how can i merge all of this with my existing Gui Project in QT? 
I need to have the subscriber inside my project but i can't understand how to make this possible. I tried to put the ws inside the project but this obv does not copile.

Comment: @Nietzsche2meetyou as per my answer your gui project should be put inside your workspace as a new package, not the other way around.